# Hyperledger Fabric error when trying to bring up test network (Windows 10)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to enable my test Hyperledger network basing on guide: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

While creating a channel via command:
`./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go`

I get following error (Error: failed to read chaincode package at 'basic.tar.gz'). I think i installed everything correctly, so what can be the case?

```
root@LAPTOP-M8AUNDFJ:/home/test_hf/fabric-samples/test-network# ./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go
Using docker and docker-compose
deploying chaincode on channel 'mychannel'
executing with the following
- CHANNEL_NAME: mychannel
- CC_NAME: basic
- CC_SRC_PATH: ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go
- CC_SRC_LANGUAGE: go
- CC_VERSION: 1.0
- CC_SEQUENCE: 1
- CC_END_POLICY: NA
- CC_COLL_CONFIG: NA
- CC_INIT_FCN: NA
- DELAY: 3
- MAX_RETRY: 5
- VERBOSE: false
Vendoring Go dependencies at ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go
/home/test_hf/fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go /home/test_hf/fabric-samples/test-network
go: finding github.com/kr/pretty v0.1.0
go: finding github.com/kr/pretty v0.2.0
go: finding github.com/go-openapi/spec v0.19.4
go: finding github.com/gobuffalo/envy v1.7.0
go: finding github.com/golang/glog v0.0.0-20160126235308-23def4e6c14b
verifying github.com/cucumber/godog@v0.8.0/go.mod: checksum mismatch
        downloaded: h1:FQ2MobPXycdSajAK3inNgLSAKGFmZqbE4S/CExz41Ys=
        go.sum:     h1:Cp3tEV1LRAyH/RuCThcxHS/+9ORZ+FMzPva2AZ5Ki+A=
/home/test_hf/fabric-samples/test-network
Finished vendoring Go dependencies
+ peer lifecycle chaincode package basic.tar.gz --path ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go --lang golang --label basic_1.0
+ res=1
++ peer lifecycle chaincode calculatepackageid basic.tar.gz
Error: failed to read chaincode package at 'basic.tar.gz': open basic.tar.gz: no such file or directory
+ PACKAGE_ID=
Error: failed to normalize chaincode path: 'go list' failed with: go: finding github.com/go-openapi/spec v0.19.4
go: finding github.com/kr/pretty v0.2.0
go: finding github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0
go: finding github.com/kr/pretty v0.1.0
verifying github.com/cucumber/godog@v0.8.0/go.mod: checksum mismatch
        downloaded: h1:FQ2MobPXycdSajAK3inNgLSAKGFmZqbE4S/CExz41Ys=
        go.sum:     h1:Cp3tEV1LRAyH/RuCThcxHS/+9ORZ+FMzPva2AZ5Ki+A=: exit status 1
Chaincode packaging has failed
Deploying chaincode failed
```

Answer (score 0):

> - peer lifecycle chaincode package basic.tar.gz --path ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go --lang golang --label basic_1.0
> - res=1

If the chaincode was being packaged successfully, res=0. This tells us that the peer binary is failing to package the asset-transfer-basic chaincode. I would try re-downloading both the fabric and fabric-samples repos and rebuilding the fabric binaries to make sure you have the latest versions of both repos.

Comment: Julian, hello, sorry for the late reply. I just tried redownloading test network and used the latest versions, but the problem stays the same.